# How to create database schema in such a way that one employee can be part of one department only?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

How to create database schema in such a way that one employee can be part of one department only.
There are three tables of a company "Employee table" "Department table" and "Region table".

Comment: Make department ID a foreign key in the Employee table

Answer (score 2):

You do this by having a `department_id` column in `employees`:

```
create table employees (
    . . . ,
    department_id int,
    . . . 
    constraint fk_employees_department foreign key (department_id) references departments(department_id)
);
```

If you want to require that each employee is *always* in a department, then use `not null`:

```
department_id int not null,
```